# I want to apply H.264 RTP video streaming over P4 SDN on Mininet

Tags: rtp

I have to do an exercise were I got h.264 video sender host, h.264 video receiver (with background traffic receiver)  host, and a background traffic generator host. All of these three are on different ip subnet connected to P4 controller.

```html
#include <core.p4>

#include <v1model.p4>

typedef bit<48> macAddr_t;

typedef bit<9> egressSpec_t;

 

header arp_t {

    bit<16> htype;

    bit<16> ptype;

    bit<8>  hlen;

    bit<8>  plen;

    bit<16> opcode;

    bit<48> hwSrcAddr;

    bit<32> protoSrcAddr;

    bit<48> hwDstAddr;

    bit<32> protoDstAddr;

}

 

header ethernet_t {

    bit<48> dstAddr;

    bit<48> srcAddr;

    bit<16> etherType;

}

 

header ipv4_t {

    bit<4>  version;

    bit<4>  ihl;

    bit<8>  diffserv;

    bit<16> totalLen;

    bit<16> identification;

    bit<3>  flags;

    bit<13> fragOffset;

    bit<8>  ttl;

    bit<8>  protocol;

    bit<16> hdrChecksum;

    bit<32> srcAddr;

    bit<32> dstAddr;

}

 

struct metadata {

}

 

struct headers {

    @name(".arp")

    arp_t      arp;

    @name(".ethernet")

    ethernet_t ethernet;

    @name(".ipv4")

    ipv4_t     ipv4;

}

 

parser ParserImpl(packet_in packet, out headers hdr, inout metadata meta, inout standard_metadata_t standard_metadata) {

    @name(".parse_arp") state parse_arp {

        packet.extract(hdr.arp);

        transition accept;

    }

    @name(".parse_ethernet") state parse_ethernet {

        packet.extract(hdr.ethernet);

        transition select(hdr.ethernet.etherType) {

            16w0x800: parse_ipv4;

            16w0x806: parse_arp;

            default: accept;

        }

    }

    @name(".parse_ipv4") state parse_ipv4 {

        packet.extract(hdr.ipv4);

        transition accept;

    }

    @name(".start") state start {

        transition parse_ethernet;

    }

}

 

control egress(inout headers hdr, inout metadata meta, inout standard_metadata_t standard_metadata) {

    register<bit<19>>(10) qdepth;  

    action do_add_qdepth() {

        qdepth.write((bit<32>)standard_metadata.egress_port, standard_metadata.deq_qdepth);

    }      

    apply {

        do_add_qdepth();

    }

}

 

control ingress(inout headers hdr, inout metadata meta, inout standard_metadata_t standard_metadata) {

    @name(".set_nhop") action set_nhop(macAddr_t dstAddr, egressSpec_t port) {

        hdr.ethernet.srcAddr = hdr.ethernet.dstAddr;


        hdr.ethernet.dstAddr = dstAddr;


        standard_metadata.egress_spec = port;

 
        hdr.ipv4.ttl = hdr.ipv4.ttl - 1;

    }

    @name("._drop") action _drop() {

        mark_to_drop(standard_metadata);

    }

    @name(".ipv4_lpm") table ipv4_lpm {

        actions = {

            set_nhop;

            _drop;

        }

        key = {

            hdr.ipv4.dstAddr: lpm;

        }

        size = 512;

        const default_action = _drop();

    }

    apply {

        ipv4_lpm.apply();
         }

}

 

control DeparserImpl(packet_out packet, in headers hdr) {

    apply {

        packet.emit(hdr.ethernet);

        packet.emit(hdr.arp);

        packet.emit(hdr.ipv4);

    }

}

 

control verifyChecksum(inout headers hdr, inout metadata meta) {

    apply {

        verify_checksum(true, { hdr.ipv4.version, hdr.ipv4.ihl, hdr.ipv4.diffserv, hdr.ipv4.totalLen, hdr.ipv4.identification, hdr.ipv4.flags, hdr.ipv4.fragOffset, hdr.ipv4.ttl, hdr.ipv4.protocol, hdr.ipv4.srcAddr, hdr.ipv4.dstAddr }, hdr.ipv4.hdrChecksum, HashAlgorithm.csum16);

    }

}

 

control computeChecksum(inout headers hdr, inout metadata meta) {

    apply {

        update_checksum(true, { hdr.ipv4.version, hdr.ipv4.ihl, hdr.ipv4.diffserv, hdr.ipv4.totalLen, hdr.ipv4.identification, hdr.ipv4.flags, hdr.ipv4.fragOffset, hdr.ipv4.ttl, hdr.ipv4.protocol, hdr.ipv4.srcAddr, hdr.ipv4.dstAddr }, hdr.ipv4.hdrChecksum, HashAlgorithm.csum16);

    }

}

 

V1Switch(ParserImpl(), verifyChecksum(), ingress(), egress(), computeChecksum(), DeparserImpl()) main;
```

I have created a json app that can host the applications topology and set the forwarding table, but I am getting an error while running it, can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I can see what you mean, I have done this integration before you only forget the priority statement otherwise should run well, please add this to your code;

after

> apply { ipv4_lpm.apply();

ADD:

```
if (hdr.ipv4.srcAddr == 0x0a000101){

        standard_metadata.priority = (bit<3>)7;

     }
```

This should fix your issue and will make the video traffic sent by your video sender host be mapped to the highest priority 7.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, yea I see that, its working well now.